# Why is object key pair with null value not passed from server to client anymore?

Tags: google-apps-script, web-applications, client-server

I have a Google application script web application where I use `google.script.run.withSuccessHandler`. Server side function returns an object where all the values are null. MaterializeCSS [autocomplete](https://materializecss.com/autocomplete.html) requires nulls

My customer today reported that the GAS web stopped working. It was 10000000% working before. I found out that the reason is a `null` as a value.

Working sample applicatin is here

https://script.google.com/macros/s/AKfycbzbg4YLndZ0zORBzgDc3ETLUdJeToUS1nKjORUa5fNxQt9syXmLlX1gDHzgS4w8iCBM9A/exec

https://script.google.com/d/1Uba73PIetb9fmrO44nwsmAd_epZTHy4lwz5bG3bURK3jqpd161JT0pf5/edit?usp=sharing

HTML code

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
  <head>
    <base target="_top">
  </head>
  <body>
    Test
<script type="text/javascript">
 console.log("test")

document.addEventListener("DOMContentLoaded", function(event) { 
    google.script.run.withSuccessHandler(afterDataReceived)
                    .returnObject()
    });

function afterDataReceived(receivedData){
  console.log(receivedData)
}
     </script>
     </body>
</html>
```

GS code

```
function doGet(e) {

  var htmlTemplate = HtmlService.createTemplateFromFile("index").evaluate()

  return htmlTemplate
}

function returnObject(){

  var object = {}

  object.a = "123"
  object.b = null
  object.c = 123

console.log(object)  
  return object
}
```

[image]

Is someone experiencing the same error? How to fix this?

Comment: Perhaps you are sending an [illegal parameter](https://developers.google.com/apps-script/guides/html/communication#parameters_and_return_values)

Comment: null is illegal? `object.b = null`

Comment: What happens if you just send `null` without a `{}`

Comment: @TheMaster it returns null. the issue is that within an object all pairs key:null are missing.

Comment: What about arrays? `[1,null,3]`?

Comment: array [1,null,3] works well as well.

Comment: `null` is a legal parameter as per [doc](https://developers.google.com/apps-script/guides/html/communication#parameters_and_return_values). Maybe create a issue in issuetracker and link it in your question ? See [tag info page](https://stackoverflow.com/tags/google-apps-script/info) for free resources and more details.

Comment: Also try `console.log(JSON.stringify(receivedData))` in case devtools has a  visual error. Also: `console.log(Object.keys(receivedData))` and `console.log(Object.values(receivedData))`

Comment: the same. the null pair is missing

Answer (score 5, accepted):

#### Issue:

If `null` is a value for a `key` in a object, the key-value pair is lost when the object is passed from server to client, though [`null` is a legal parameter](https://developers.google.com/apps-script/guides/html/communication#parameters_and_return_values).I can confirm the issue.

#### Solution:

The issue is reported [here](https://issuetracker.google.com/issues/204502662). Add a star to the issue, if anyone else has the same issue.

As a typical workaround for illegal parameters, Use `JSON.stringify()` on the server side, pass the `string` to the client and `JSON.parse()` it client side to get nulls inside a object.

#### Server:

```
function returnObject(){
  return JSON.stringify({a:1,b:null,c:3});
}
```

#### Client:

```
document.addEventListener("DOMContentLoaded",    
 function(event) { 
  google.script.run
    .withSuccessHandler(afterDataReceived)
    .returnObject()
});

function afterDataReceived(receivedData){
  console.log(JSON.parse(receivedData));
}
```

Comment: I have just used your "workaround solution". Much better than mine. thanx